which Xero API to Use to Get Account Transaction Data?
I am looking for this API which will return this report data. Does Xero providing any API for same. If yes then please let me know the API details for this.
I am looking for this API which will return this report data.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Xero doesn't currently have the ability to return the account transaction report through API at this stage.
Every transaction created in Xero that effects the general ledger creates an accounting journal in the background. Typically you can only see these journals in the Journal report found in the Report Centre, however they are also available via the API.
If you pull all the journals from the organisation you'll be able to build your own reports as required. To do this you would need to perform an initial process to retrieve the complete set of journals. If these were then stored locally it would only need to be a one-time process. Subsequent updates would only need to retrieve any new journals.
